# Numpy Array Subtraction

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

How would I go about comparing two different numpy arrays to create a third array? I want to write a loop that goes through two arrays and prints a new array "c" with only the values that are not in a or b

For example say I have

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I want it to print:

```
c = [5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: c=list(set(b).difference(set(a)))

Comment: Those are *lists*. Are you actually working with `numpy.ndarray`s?

Answer (score 3):

You can use set difference operation in Numpy: `numpy.setdiff1d`.
From the [Numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html#numpy.setdiff1d):

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1])
>>> b = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> np.setdiff1d(a, b)
array([1, 2])
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out explicitly (though the example from docs is crafted well enough to show implicitly) that `setdiff1d` doesn't care about repetition in the array. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The OP does specify which array should be subtracted from the other. It seems he wants all unique values in either array: `a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1])
b = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
c = np.concatenate((np.setdiff1d(a, b), np.setdiff1d(b,a)))`